# Is there anything that i can replace AbsolutePath.Contains with?

Tags: c#, uri

I have a Uri that contains a part of the path that i am putting in the if block. Its something like

```
if (absUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("W3C//DTD%20XHTML%201.1//EN"))
```

I want to replace .Contains part with something more reliable and robust as if there is some piece of string after //EN, even that will satisfy the if block. The whole path is something like this: C:/Users/a/desktop/fol/W3C//DTD%20XHTML%201.1//EN. 
Is there any method?

Comment: I think Contains very nicely solves the purpose. It will match even if there is something after //EN. It will not match if string contains something after //EN if you are using string.EndsWith ()

Comment: What is the problem in using "Contains"?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something like .EndsWith i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well it shouldn't matter if there's something after the "//EN" as the string will still contain your search term.

You mention you want something more reliable & robust so what problem are you seeing?

As you've realised `.EndsWith` will fail if there is anything after the "//EN" or if that varies, but I don't think it's any more reliable than `.Contains`. In fact I'd expect them to be as reliable as each other.